# Can I at the same time use Personal VPN on home router/mobile hotspot and company VPN on employers laptop?

Tags: vpn

I need to travel aborad for few weeks. My company needs my laptop IP from strictely perticular country. I can do that with VPN on router or on my mobile hotspot.
Also for many a times I need to use company VPN for some of my work. I was thinking of installing personal VPN on home router for right geolocation IP. But the question is, can I at the same time use company VPN app on my employers laptop? Will Cisco Anyconnect detect presence of another VPN in use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup internet connection in a way vpn logs would think I'm logging from different country](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262086/how-to-setup-internet-connection-in-a-way-vpn-logs-would-think-im-logging-from)

Comment: Is your IT has security policy to avoid using laptop in some contries?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it from the technical standpoint?
Probably, as long as the "outer" VPN is on a different device like you do with your phone.

Would the VPN be able to detect this?
Kind of. The smaller MTU of the link can be a sign, that double encapsulation is done. Some VPN products even have problems to properly work with such a reduced MTU. But, since reduced MTU can be normal in some environments, this is not a clear indicator of you using a VPN inside a VPN. But if you are using a VPN on your home router it will be visible, that the same originating IP address is sometimes using a small MTU (when using the VPN) and a "normal" MTU at other times (when not using a VPN). If the company is watching for this kind of behavior, they can detect what you are doing.

Could you get into trouble for doing this?
You've stated yourself that your company "needs my laptop IP from strictly particular country". So what you are doing is explicitly bypassing company policy, which clearly can get you into trouble.